# Very Slow Linq to SQL Select Performance on WP7

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7

I'm having a problem with Linq to SQL performance on Windows Phone 7, but I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong (I have almost no experience with Linq to SQL, and the more I read, the more confused I'm getting *sigh*).

**Background**

I have a local SQL CE database with five tables, two columns in each (`int` primary key & `nvarchar` value, plus indexes), and about a 100,000 entries in each table. The DB is around 20MB in size and is implemented following the guidelines in Microsoft's own MVVM local database sample.

**Problem**

After simplifying as much as I can, I have a query in my view model that looks like this:

```
var query =
(
  from t1 in db.table1
    join t2 in db.table2 on t1.id equals t2.id
    join t3 in db.table3 on t1.id equals t3.id
    join t4 in db.table4 on t1.id equals t4.id
    join t5 in db.table5 on t1.id equals t5.id
  where
    SqlMethods.Like(t5.value, "%"+searchTerm+"%")
  select new Results
  {
    Field1 = t1.value,
    Field2 = t2.value,
    Field3 = t3.value,
    Field4 = t4.value,
    Field5 = t5.value,
  }
).Take(100);

SearchResults = new ObservableCollection<Results>(query);
```

This products the following SQL:

```
SELECT TOP (100)
  [t0].[value] AS [Field1],
  [t1].[value] AS [Field2],
  [t2].[value] AS [Field3],
  [t3].[value] AS [Field4],
  [t4].[value] AS [Field5]
FROM
  [table1] AS [t0],
  [table2] AS [t1],
  [table3] AS [t2],
  [table4] AS [t3],
  [table5] AS [t4]
WHERE ([t4].[value] LIKE @p0)
  AND ([t0].[id] = [t4].[id])
  AND ([t0].[id] = [t3].[id])
  AND ([t0].[id] = [t2].[id])
  AND ([t0].[id] = [t1].[id])
```

The problem is, when the search term is very specific (only one result), it averages around **5 seconds** to execute. This is before I add any of the other requirements, like multiple where clauses, ranking, ordering etc. Even if I search for what I know to be the first row in the database, it still takes around 5 seconds.

If I change approach and search for something very common (like 'the'), it only takes around **100ms** to execute. I know `Like` with wildcards is more complicated than a straight `==` comparison, but I don't know why the performance is so different.

(I know it's a useless comparison, as they're apples and oranges, but I previously executed similar queries on the same database written in MySQL, and they consistently got results in around 0.3-0.4s regardless of what I searched for).

Am I missing something really obvious? I've followed Microsoft's examples and read many tutorials online, but I can't find a reason why this query is so slow. Many thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you try to execute the same query *without* using LINQ. I *suspect* you'll see the same performance, which means it's not LINQ that's to blame at all. Bear in mind that with a wildcard search like this, the database basically can't use any indexes - whereas with a straight equality match, it should be able to get to the right entry very quickly indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Jon. You're right, I just profiled the same database on my desktop using that generated SQL and received a similar performance ratio (1.2s for the specific query vs. 0.02s for the generic query). I didn't realise wildcards would have that much of a performance hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SIMPLE COMMON SENSE.

- You run that on a low power phone and make a table scan query.

> SqlMethods.Like(t5.value, "%"+searchTerm+"%")

means no index grabs, this is a table scan.

> ).Take(100);

Means: stop after 100 items are found.

Now, witha very common word ("the") this may mean only 100 items are processed at all. With a more uncommon word it may have to run half the table to get 100 items. Table scanning half that database will take time. Simlpe.

In general, sql is badly prepared for word parsing in texts-  this is why real sql server ahs full text indexing. Running that (%word%) on a low pwoer hardware (wp7= naturally is slow.

There is absolutely nothing in here that points to LINQ being a problem. LINQ transaltes that likely into a quite efficient SQL query within the perforamnce boundaries you define in the query - which is the worst thing you can do to a database, sadly.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I think my common sense is running low after staring at this for so long! Your explanation is very clear, I guess I just thought (hoped?) that somehow my lack of understanding of Linq was to blame. I guess I need to reformulate my query and/or data to avoid this wildcard kind of situation, but I'm struggling. Anyway, thanks for your time and pointing out what should be obvious :)